# Add a dependency to C# Windows Forms Application in MS Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, log4net

Please advise how to add a dependency to C# Windows Forms Application project in MS Visual Studio Community 2015. I'v found instruction:

> Select a project in the Solution Explorer, and then choose Project
>   Dependencies from the Project menu.

But there's no 'Project Dependencies' in the 'Project' menu. I need to add log4net dependency. Thanks for your patience with the VS beginner :)

[image]

Comment: You probably want to use *Add Reference* to add a reference to System.Windows.Forms or log4net? Project dependencies are normally resolved automatically and only need to be changed if you want to make sure a certain project is definitely built before another one.

Comment: I allready have such reference in the References. But how is it related to addidng log4net dependency? Pardon my ignorance.

Comment: log4net is not related to System.Windows.Forms. Where did you find that you  should add a reference or dependency to windows forms? What is it you are actually trying to achieve? Use log4net in your program?

Comment: I suspect you should be reading a different tutorial if the one you are using can't even get the terminology correct!

Comment: It's quotation from MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/zk4ahe0t.aspx I didn't know the correct terminology as I'm a .NET ans VS studio beginner. Still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) with [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right  click on `References` and select `Add Reference`